# Raspberry pi 0w is making a humming/buzzing sound?

Tags: raspbian, pi-zero-w, battery

I have a problem with my raspberry pi 0w. The SOC is making a buzzing sound when connected to a li-po.
The li-po is 3.7 volts and 1200mah and it is connected to an Adafruit 500c (https://www.adafruit.com/product/1944)
I also use the Adafruit 500c to boost the voltage to 5v. I'm suspecting the issue is from the power supply and I'm just wanting to know if it is dangerous or if I can do anything about it.

Comment: are you really sure that the RPi is making the sound?

Answer (score 3):

Its probably "Coil whining" you hear from the inductor in the Adafruit PowerBooster.

Ref.: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetically_induced_acoustic_noise